# sending ajax request to a module service without no ajaxController

Tags: zend-framework3, ajax-request

I want to count how many times my menu items are clicked. for this task, I have a visited cell in my `menu` table that is retrieved by some models. the menu items are shown on my `layout.phtml` each specified by their `id` and I am trying to use ajax for this matter as below:

```
### menu items in layout.phtml

<li><a href="#" id="menuItems" data_id="mydata511">about</a></li>

### ajax code
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a#menuItems').click(function () {
            var data={};
            data.id =$(this).attr("data_id");
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url  :'../../../module/Application/src/Model/visitCounter.php',
                data :data,
                success: function(data){
                },
                error:function(){
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

the `visitCounter.php` is a service model that gets the variables via POST method do the rest of the work but the problem is how to send this ajax request to the service model page. I wonder if there is a way to achieve that without any controller.
I really appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: Well.. You can map this call in .htaccess to a single php and do your work at there. But not in zend application without controller.

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ thank you for your response, but this is kind of a simple thing I am trying to do,If I should carried it out through Controller I am not able benefit this idea for different modules belonging to the application. every items on menu are mapped to these varied modules, with this approach it seems impossible.